# XML into Python, import is spaced out

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

**If you're going to give me a negative point, at least comment why. I'm just trying to understand.

Has anyone run into this? I haven't been able to figure it out. I have a large XML file I am trying to parse, and when I import it into Python using soup (or anything really) it outputs with an added spaced in between each character. It's the strangest thing.

Example of output:

```
H e a d e r &gt; 

     P I E S V e r s i o n &gt; 6 . 5 / P I E S V e r s i o n &gt; 

     S u b m i s s i o n T y p e &gt; F U L L / S u b m i s s i o n T y p e &gt; 

     P a r e n t D U N S N u m b e r &gt; 0 5 5 4 3 3 1 9 7 / P a r e n t D U N S N u m b e r &gt; 

     C u r r e n c y C o d e &gt; U S D / C u r r e n c y C o d e &gt; 

     L a n g u a g e C o d e &gt; E N / L a n g u a g e C o d e &gt; 

     T e c h n i c a l C o n t a c t &gt; B r e n t   B u s h n e l l / T e c h n i c a l C o n t a c t &gt; 

     C o n t a c t E m a i l &gt; B r e n t . B u s h n e l l @ g a t e s . c o m / C o n t a c t E m a i l &gt; 

 / H e a d e r &gt; 



<Header>
<PIESVersion>6.5</PIESVersion>
<SubmissionType>FULL</SubmissionType>
<ParentDUNSNumber>055433197</ParentDUNSNumber>
<CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
<LanguageCode>EN</LanguageCode>
<TechnicalContact>Brent Bushnell</TechnicalContact>
<ContactEmail>Brent.Bushnell@gates.com</ContactEmail>
</Header>
```

Portion of code that should work:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

infile = open('GATES.xml','r')
contents = infile.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents,'xml')

bullets = {}
attributes = {}
attr_ids = {}
attr_test = {}

for part in soup.find_all('Item'):

    # --Pulls bullet point data from PIES File-------------------------------------------------------
    bullets[part.find('PartNumber').get_text()] = [x.get_text() for x in part.find_all('Description')]

    # --Pulls attribute data from PIES File----------------------------------------------------------
    for x in part.find_all('PartNumber'):

        partNum = x.get_text()

        for v in part.find_all('ProductAttribute'):
            attr_value = v.get_text()
            attr_id = v.get('AttributeID')

            attr_ids[attr_id] = attr_value

        attributes[partNum] = [attr_ids]
```

Comment: what have you tried ?

Comment: can you provide a sample of the XML file that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Can you add the code snippet?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We need to be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: well so far just a simple as this and the import looks like that.

infile = open('GATES.xml','r')
contents = infile.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents,'xml')

Comment: Idk if it's the XML file that is weird

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. How exactly did you get "Example of output"? Your code does not output anything (neither print to stdout nor write to file).

Comment: it's the actual huge xml file I'm working with. its not reading as an xml. Thanks for the time guys, but I'm not going to waste any more of yours.